# Displaying the "version history" menu

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am the owner of a sharepoint (online) site, and enabled a library files versioning.
I see the "version history" option, but there is an user who can't see it. I tried granting different (all!) permissions, but he still can not see this. What I'm missing?

[image: What the user is seeing]
[image: What I expect to be displayed]

Answer (score 1):

Normally, as long as Versioning is turned on, you can view the Version History option.

**It is recommended that you do the following troubleshooting：**

1.Switch to the classic mode for viewing

[image]

[image]

2.Create a new Document library to test to see if the userself is the problem

3.Clear the browser cache or test with another browser